# Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager :error occurred at jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I am getting this error in jsp log file as handleJspException ,how to solve this issue in jsp can anyone suggest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ page import = "com.agastha.beans.*,com.agastha.util.*,java.util.*,java.math.*,java.sql.Timestamp" %>
<%@ page import = "com.agastha.UrlCrypt.QueryCrypt,com.agastha.UrlCrypt.RequestParameterObject"%>
<jsp:useBean id="_search" class="com.agastha.beans.SearchBean" scope="request"/><jsp:useBean id="_patient" class="com.agastha.beans.Patient" scope="request"/><jsp:setProperty name="_search" property="*"/>
<html>
<head>

Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert string "543" to class "java.util.Map" for attribute "location": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert string "543" to class "java.util.Map" for attribute "location": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getValueFromPropertyEditorManager(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:873)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.convert(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:267)
```